# Event system using callback functions in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, event-handling, boost, type-safety

I am learning C++ and have been trying to create an event system for use in a small game. This will be the mechanism by which game entities communicate. I would be eternally grateful if someone with experience could critique my code. Running through it myself, I'm a little concerned about the use of Runtime Type Information (RTTI). I know that this is discouraged but I can't find any alternative to providing some basic type safety.

```
class EventDispatcher
{
public:
    /**
     * Callback function type for event handling.
     */
    template<typename EventType>
    struct Callback
    {
        /**
         * Constructor.
         */
        Callback(boost::function<void(const EventType& event)> callback) :
        handler(callback)
        {
            // Nothing to do.
        }

        /**
         * Callback function.
         */
        boost::function<void(const EventType& event)> handler;
    };

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    EventDispatcher();

    /**
     * Destructor.
     */
    ~EventDispatcher();

    /**
     * Subscribe to receive events.
     *
     * @param callback Event handler callback.
     */
    template <typename EventType>
    void Subscribe(Callback<EventType> callback)
    {
        GetSpecificDispatcher<EventType>()->Subscribe(callback);
    }

    /**
     * Immediately broadcast an event to subscribers.
     *
     * @param args... Event constructor arguments.
     */
    template <typename EventType, typename... Arguments>
    void Broadcast(const Arguments... args)
    {
        GetSpecificDispatcher<EventType>()->Broadcast(EventType(args...));
    }

    /**
     * Queue an event to be broadcast to subscribers on the next Update
     * call.
     *
     * @param args... Event constructor arguments.
     */
    template <typename EventType, typename... Arguments>
    void Enqueue(const Arguments... args)
    {
        GetSpecificDispatcher<EventType>()->Enqueue(EventType(args...));
    }

    /**
     * Broadcasts all events in the queue to subscribers.
     */
    void Update()
    {
        for (auto iter = dispatchers.begin(); iter != dispatchers.end(); ++iter)
        {
            iter->second->Update();
        }
    }

protected:
    /**
     * Event specific dispatcher interface.
     */
    class ISpecificDispatcher
    {
    public:
        virtual void Update() = 0;
    };

    /**
     * Event specific dispatcher.
     */
    template<typename EventType>
    class SpecificDispatcher : public ISpecificDispatcher
    {
    public:
        /**
         * Subscribe to receive events.
         *
         * @param callback Event handler callback.
         */
        void Subscribe(Callback<EventType> callback)
        {
            callbacks.push_back(callback);
        }

        /**
         * Immediately broadcast an event to subscribers.
         *
         * @param args... Event constructor arguments.
         */
        template <typename... Arguments>
        void Broadcast(const Arguments... args)
        {
            EventType event(args...);
            for (const Callback<EventType>& callback : callbacks)
            {
                callback.handler(event);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Queue an event to be broadcast to subscribers on the next Update
         * call.
         *
         * @param args... Event constructor arguments.
         */
        template <typename... Arguments>
        void Enqueue(const Arguments... args)
        {
            eventQueue.push(EventType(args...));
        }

        /**
         * Broadcasts all events in the queue to subscribers.
         */
        virtual void Update()
        {
            while (!eventQueue.empty())
            {
                const EventType& event = eventQueue.front();
                for (const Callback<EventType>& callback : callbacks)
                {
                    callback.handler(event);
                }
                eventQueue.pop();
            }
        }

    private:
        /**
         * Queued events.
         */
        std::queue<EventType> eventQueue;

        /**
         * Event callback handlers.
         */
        std::vector<Callback<EventType>> callbacks;
    };

    /**
     * Returns a pointer to the specific dispatcher for the event type.
     * A specific dispatcher is first created if one does not exist.
     */
    template<typename EventType>
    boost::shared_ptr<SpecificDispatcher<EventType>> GetSpecificDispatcher()
    {
        auto iter = dispatchers.find(typeid(EventType).name());
        if (iter == dispatchers.end())
        {
            // A specific dispatcher was not found.
            // We better create one!
            boost::shared_ptr<SpecificDispatcher<EventType>> specificDispatcher(new SpecificDispatcher<EventType>());
            dispatchers[typeid(EventType).name()] = specificDispatcher;
            return specificDispatcher;
        }
        else
        {
            return boost::static_pointer_cast<SpecificDispatcher<EventType>>(iter->second);
        }
    }

private:
    /**
     * Event specific dispatchers.
     */
    std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<ISpecificDispatcher>> dispatchers;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to update to C++20 as we go along, beginning with using modern Standard Library rather than Boost.

We need to include some headers:

```
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <queue>
```

`EventDispatcher` declares a constructor and destructor but never defines them (along with comments that add absolutely zero value):

> ```
> /**
>  * Constructor.
>  */
> EventDispatcher();
>
> /**
>  * Destructor.
>  */
> ~EventDispatcher();
> ```

We could define them inline with `=default`, but I think it's better to omit them entirely and let the compiler generate implicit ones.

Conversely, `ISpecificDispatcher` doesn't have a destructor, but really needs one, to make it a virtual destructor, since it's used as a base class:

```
class ISpecificDispatcher
{
public:
    virtual ~ISpecificDispatcher() = default;
    virtual void Update() = 0;
};
```

Without this, `delete` of a base-class pointer will fail to call subclass destructors.

---

Now we've dealt with compiler warnings, let's look at the interface.  I'd like to be able to subscribe my function:

```
d.Subscribe([](const int& i){ std::cout << i << '\n'; });
```

But the function only accepts `EventDispatcher::Callback` objects:

```
d.Subscribe(EventDispatcher::Callback<int>{[](const int& i){ std::cout << i << '\n'; }});
```

We can make that a bit easier to use, with an overload of `Subscribe`:

```
template<typename EventType, typename F>
void Subscribe(F&& callback)
{
    Subscribe(Callback<EventType>{std::forward<F>(callback)});
}
```

which gets us a bit closer:

```
d.Subscribe<int>([](const int& i){ std::cout << i << '\n'; });
```

---

The `Callback` class seems too heavyweight.  I simply replaced with

```
template<typename EventType>
using Callback = std::function<void(const EventType& event)>;
```

---

I don't like the construction of the event within `Broadcast()` and `Enqueue`.  This forces the use of `(…)` rather than `{…}`, and doesn't seem to save anything at the call site.  If we simply accept a ready-constructed `EventType`, like this:

```
template<typename EventType>
void Enqueue(EventType&& event)
{
    GetSpecificDispatcher<EventType>()->Enqueue(std::forward<EventType>(event));
}
```

then the call site changes from

```
d.Enqueue<event>(1,2);
```

to

```
d.Enqueue(event{1,2});
```

That's no longer, and gives the caller more options for constructing the event (which could be especially useful for factory-constructed event objects, which might not have public constructors).

There's certainly no need for `SpecificDispatcher` to work with anything other than `EventType`, since that's what its methods are always called with:

```
    /**
     * Immediately broadcast an event to subscribers.
     */
    void Broadcast(const EventType& event)
    {
        for (auto const& callback: callbacks) {
            callback.handler(event);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Queue an event to be broadcast to subscribers on the next Update
     * call.
     */
    void Enqueue(EventType event)
    {
        eventQueue.push(std::move(event));
    }
```

`Update()` repeats the logic of `Broadcast()` in its inner loop - better to simply call it:

```
    /**
     * Broadcast all events in the queue to subscribers.
     */
    virtual void Update()
    {
        while (!eventQueue.empty()) {
            auto const& event = eventQueue.front();
            Broadcast(event);
            eventQueue.pop();
        }
    }
```

---

`GetSpecificDispatcher` can be simpler, if we take advantage of `operator[]` creating a default (i.e. null pointer) object as value:

```
template<typename EventType>
std::shared_ptr<SpecificDispatcher<EventType>> GetSpecificDispatcher()
{
    auto& specificDispatcher = dispatchers[typeid(EventType).name()];
    if (!specificDispatcher) {
        specificDispatcher.reset(new SpecificDispatcher<EventType>());
    }
    return std::static_pointer_cast<SpecificDispatcher<EventType>>(specificDispatcher);
}
```

It's wasteful to do string comparisons here - just use `typeid` directly as the key type (okay, we need to wrap a reference for this):

```
#include <typeinfo>

namespace typeinfo
{
    using ref = std::reference_wrapper<const std::type_info>;

    struct hash {
        auto operator()(ref code) const {return code.get().hash_code();}
    };
    struct equality {
        auto operator()(ref lhs, ref rhs) const {return lhs.get() == rhs.get();}
    };
}
```

```
private:
    using DispatcherPointer = std::shared_ptr<ISpecificDispatcher>;

    std::unordered_map<typeinfo::ref, DispatcherPointer,
                       typeinfo::hash, typeinfo::equality
                       > dispatchers = {};
```

---

There's no means to unsubscribe a callback when it's no longer needed.  I think that `subscribe()` perhaps ought to return a token that can be used for subsequent removal.

---

## Modified code

Applying these changes, we arrive at something that may be a better start for moving to compile-time event types:

```
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <queue>
#include <typeinfo>

namespace typeinfo
{
    using ref = std::reference_wrapper<const std::type_info>;

    struct hash {
        auto operator()(ref code) const
        { return code.get().hash_code(); }
    };
    struct equality {
        auto operator()(ref lhs, ref rhs) const
        { return lhs.get() == rhs.get(); }
    };
}

class EventDispatcher
{
    /**
     * Callback function type for event handling.
     */
    template<typename EventType>
    using Callback = std::function<void(const EventType& event)>;

public:
    template<typename EventType, typename F>
    void subscribe(F&& callback)
    {
        GetDispatcher<EventType>()->subscribe(Callback<EventType>{std::forward<F>(callback)});
    }

    /**
     * Immediately broadcast an event to subscribers.
     *
     * @param args... Event constructor arguments.
     */
    template <typename EventType>
    void broadcast(const EventType& event)
    {
        GetDispatcher<EventType>()->broadcast(event);
    }

    /**
     * Queue an event to be broadcast to subscribers on the next Update
     * call.
     */
    template<typename EventType>
    void enqueue(EventType&& event)
    {
        GetDispatcher<EventType>()->enqueue(std::forward<EventType>(event));
    }

    /**
     * Broadcasts all events in the queue to subscribers.
     */
    void update()
    {
        for (auto& d: dispatchers) {
            d.second->update();
        }
    }

protected:
    /**
     * Event specific dispatcher interface.
     */
    class DispatcherBase
    {
    public:
        virtual ~DispatcherBase() = default;
        virtual void update() = 0;
    };

    /**
     * Event specific dispatcher.
     */
    template<typename EventType>
    class Dispatcher : public DispatcherBase
    {
        std::vector<Callback<EventType>> callbacks = {};
        std::queue<EventType> eventQueue = {};

    public:
        void subscribe(Callback<EventType> callback)
        {
            callbacks.push_back(std::move(callback));
        }

        void broadcast(const EventType& event)
        {
            for (auto const& callback: callbacks) {
                callback(event);
            }
        }

        void enqueue(EventType event)
        {
            eventQueue.push(std::move(event));
        }

        void update() override
        {
            while (!eventQueue.empty()) {
                auto const& event = eventQueue.front();
                broadcast(event);
                eventQueue.pop();
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Returns a pointer to the specific dispatcher for the event type.
     * A specific dispatcher is first created if one does not exist.
     */
    template<typename EventType>
    std::shared_ptr<Dispatcher<EventType>> GetDispatcher()
    {
        auto& specificDispatcher = dispatchers[typeid(EventType)];
        if (!specificDispatcher) {
            specificDispatcher.reset(new Dispatcher<EventType>());
        }
        return std::static_pointer_cast<Dispatcher<EventType>>(specificDispatcher);
    }

private:
    using DispatcherPointer = std::shared_ptr<DispatcherBase>;

    std::unordered_map<typeinfo::ref, DispatcherPointer,
                       typeinfo::hash, typeinfo::equality
                       > dispatchers = {};
};
```